# Dependency injection in restful WS

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, ejb, jax-ws

I have simple restful WS

```
@Path("basic")
public class ServiceRS
{

   private IServiceJAX service;

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   public String find(@FormParam("searchRequest") final String searchRequest)
   {
//...
      final List<Info> response = service.find(search);
//...
   }

}
```

Where `IServiceJAX` is `@Local` interface of jax-webservice. 
Can I inject `IServiceJAX` to `ServiceRS` using annotation?
I don't want use JNDI lookup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can. Although I suppose there are other ways, I have successfully run a simple test project with a `@Stateless` `@WebService`, `@Local` implementation of an `interface`, injected through `@EJB` annotation into a `@Stateless` RESTFul web service annotated with `@Path`.

This is not properly a CDI injection as you have demanded, but it works nicely and probably fits your needs anyway.

**IServiceJAX** class:

```
public interface IServiceJAX {
    public String hello(String txt);
}
```

**IServiceJAXImpl** class:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
@Local
@Stateless
public class IServiceJAXImpl implements IServiceJAX {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    @Override
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

**ServiceRS** class:

```
@Path("basic")
@Stateless
public class ServiceRS {

    @EJB private IServiceJAX wsi;

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String result(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return wsi.hello(id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you prefer CDI injection, you can keep the above code and simply remove `@Local` and `@Stateless` annotations from `IServiceJAXImpl`. You can inject an instance of this class using:

```
@Inject private IServiceJAX wsi;
```

instead of

```
@EJB private IServiceJAX wsi;
```