# Cant inject Bean class into Restfull WebService (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, persistence, jax-rs

I'm trying to save data acquired by Rest web service to database using hibernate/persistence.
In one of my web modules i implemented that service. Database ejb connector is placed in EJB module. They are parts of EAR application.
Every time when i call pb.addDevice() im getting  java.lang.NullPointerException when puting proper url with params in browser(worked till i wanted to save it to Database). Can't find what is wrong with it. I'm using jboss 6.1.0 Final.

tried answer of [Dependency injection in restful WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314073/dependency-injection-in-restful-ws)

and after following it step by step im alse getting nullpointer also

PS. when i changed from

```
@EJB
PersistenceBean pb;
```

to

```
PersistenceBean pb = new PersistenceBean();
```

i got null pointer on  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

code:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/RestService")
public class RestPush  {

@EJB
PersistenceBean pb; 

    @GET
    @Path("/RegisterDevice")
    public void registerDevice(
        @QueryParam("deviceId") String deviceId){

        Device d = new Device(true);
        d.setId = deviceId;
        pb.addDevice(d);
    }
}
```

and EJB class:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "PersistenceBean")
public class PersistenceBean {
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "PersistentUnitName")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

private void persist(Object o, EntityManager entityManager) {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.severe("Error writing to DB: " + e);
        logger.severe("" + e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
}
  public void addDevice(Device d) {
    try {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
    if (persist(device, em)) {
            logger.info("Device with id : " + device.getId()
                    + " has been added ");
} else {
            logger.info("Failed to add device with id: " + device.getId());
} catch (Exception e) {
        logger.severe("PersistenceBean: Could not save device.");
        e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

upadate:

```
EAR
  --EarContent
    --META-INF
       --application.xml
EJB
  --package in ejbModule
    --PersistenceBean
    --Device
  --META-INF
    --ejb-jar.xml
    --MANIFEST.MF
    --persistence.xml
    --beans.xml

Web
  --package in webModule
    --Rest (auto generated class while creating Webservice)
    --RestPush
  --WebContent
    --META-INF
      --MANIFEST.MF
    --WEB-INF
      --web.xml
      --beans.xml
```

stack trace:

```
`10:23:28,629 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/RestWeb].[Resteasy]] Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at package.RestPush.registerDevice(RestPush.java:68) [:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_27]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@EJB` annotation is not supposed to work for all objects.

For this to work you need to use CDI, so substitute the `@EJB` with `@Inject` and your bean will be correctly injected.

See also: [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service)

EDIT:

Also be sure to add `beans.xml` to every jar/war archive containing classes you want to inject or be injected. It goes into `META-INF` for jars and `WEB-INF` for wars.

Your REST application class `packaget.Rest` should extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` as in:

```
@ApplicationPath("/root-path") 
public class Rest extends Application 
{ 
}
```

And according to the documentation [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasy-CDIIntegration) on JBoss 6.1  REST and CDI should work out of the box. If you specify the org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher and the org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap you are probably messing up the RestEasy/CDI classloading.

So your `web.xml` should look as:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/…"> 
</web-app>
```

Anyway, I pushed a working example on [github](https://github.com/carlopellegriniarchijcom/rest-ee6-example.git)

Comment: well i tried that before and changing annotation from EJB to Inject changes nothing, still null pointer when calling pb.addDevice(d);

Comment: Are you sure that your objects are getting injected? Where did you put the CDI `beans.xml` file?

Comment: mayby that is the problem i don't have any beans.xml file

Comment: Definitely, you need it in `WEB-INF` fro WAR modules or in `META-INF` for jar (ejb or lib) modules. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html

Comment: ok i created beans.xml  web module, code:      

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>`

but it didn't help

Comment: Could you post your EAR structure? Remember that if `beans.xml` is not in the module/lib jars also, they will not be scanned by CDI.

Comment: On Web/WebContent move beans.xml from META-INF to WEB-INF (otherwise it's not located). Add beans.xml to EJB/META-INF. Remember to use @Inject.

Comment: again thanks for helping, but still NullPointer when trying to access pb.addDevice(); ... Tried with `@Inject` and few types of Beans annotations eaven with `@EJB` - excepting miracle

Comment: Mmmm.. could you post also the exception? (full stacktrace)

Comment: i have tried answer of  [Dependency injection in restful WS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314073/dependency-injection-in-restful-ws)

and after following it step by step im alse getting nullpointer also

Comment: don't know if it's related but when instead of Rest i'm using Servlet - dependency injections works perfect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31341/discussion-between-carlo-pellegrini-and-user2377971)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `/src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml`. This will enable injection.

Answer (score 1):

I has similar issue, for me the problem was creating my RESTful bean on my own with constructor, which was dumb while using EJBs and @EJB injection:

PROBLEM:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    public RestApplication() {
        singletons.add(new RestService());
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

Hope it might save sb's time.